# phpmailer_subject№

Tags: php, phpmailer

помогите пожалуйста, использую форму php mailer для отправки сообщений с формы. Задача - Что бы тема письма всегда была с числом +1. Постоянно продолжая последовательность. Пример "Заявка №1", "Заявка №2" и т.д. Через неделю например это будет "Заявка №150". Такое реально в php mailer? Спасибо за ответ и помощь. ( так как письма всегда идут от одного отправителя, одному отправителю, прим. "от юсера_1" к "юсеру_2" без разных тем очень сложно следить за входящей информацией).

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$text_message = $_POST['user_textMessage'];

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'New Zayavka №';
$mail->Body    = '
    <h3>Заявка</h3><br>
    Имя: ' . $name . ' <br>
    Имейл: ' . $email . ' <br>
    Сообщение: ' . $text_message . ' <br>
    Телефон: ' . $phone . '';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```

Comment: Не отправляйте AltBody, если оно Вам не нужно. Тогда текстовый клиент хотя бы попытается отобразить текст из html, а не покажет бесполезную рыбу из примера. Не забывайте `htmlspecialchars` для переменных в теле письма

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что если я использую например клиент gmail, альтбоди мне не нужен вообще?

Comment: Вы же не знаете где будет читать письмо получатель. Предпочтительнее всё таки реализовать текстовую часть.

Comment: в конкретно этом случае знаю - будет читать письмо в клиенте gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно где-то хранить текущее значение счетчика. При создании письма считывать это значение, увеличивать на 1 и записывать обратно.

Варианты хранилища:

- База данных. Это самый простой способ реализации. Тем более, что в БД уже реализована потокобезопасная работа с автоинкрементом
- Внешний файл. Тут блокировки придется реализовывать самому

Comment: Anton Shchyrov я пока что очень слабо ориентируюсь в программировании, через базу данных это реализовывать долго? можно это сделать например "Тему письма задать как переменную с функцией числа +1 в конце", и например после отправки что бы мой файл mail.php (в котором конфиг php.mailera) просто сохранял последнюю переменную ? Отправилось первое письмо, он сохранил у себя тема "Заявка №1". Когдак опять отправляет письмо он уже будет отталкиваться от Заявки №1 и соотсвественно сделает +1 и сохранит в себе - Заявка №2. Или это все сложно реализуемо, и не стоит новичку заморачиваться?

Comment: Если для новичка - попробуйте для начала хранить текущий номер в сессии

Comment: @vp_arth 3 можете подсказать реализацию? или где посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Решение с сессией:

```
<?php 

session_start();  

$id = $_SESSION['mail_subject_id'] ?? 1;

// ...
$mail->Subject = "Order#{$id}";
// ...

$_SESSION['mail_subject_id'] = $id + 1;
```

При недостаточном уровне персистентности сессий придётся пользоваться другим хранилищем: кеш(memcached, redis), база данных, файл и т.п.
Всё зависит от потребностей приложения.

Comment: наверное нубский вопрос, но сколько будет длиться сессия? Или это на постоянной основе? (когда произойдет конец сессии)

Comment: Максимальное время жизни сессии настраивается в php отдельно. Также как и время жизни куки с идентификатором сессии. Переход в другой браузер или очистка куки вручную начнёт новую сессию.

Comment: пробовал как нуб скопировать Ваш вариант, ничего не получилось...Ругаеться на строку 8 а именно на переменную $id, а именно  на "?? ". Тупо копировал на верх моего конфига php.mailera session_start();  + переменную, в сабжект = тему и в самый низ переменную сессии. Ладно, спасибо за помощь, попробую разобраться попозже.

Comment: `??` - оператор текущей версии языка php. Вероятно, Вы пользуетесь более ранней. В данном случае `$a??$b` можно заменить на `!empty($a)?$a:$b`